# Google plus integrating: Unable to load visible circles

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to get list of people info from google plus in my app: friends profile image URL, visible name and id.

Here's [an official google plus integrating tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people). I make the test app by this tutorial and trapped on error:

```
Error requesting visible circles: Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

Implementing the Google Api Client:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
```

Here's onResult:

```
@Override
public void onResult(People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {

    if (loadPeopleResult.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
        PersonBuffer personBuffer = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer();
        try {
            int count = personBuffer.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Log.d("TEST", "Display name: " + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
            }
        } finally {
            personBuffer.close();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("TEST", "Error requesting visible circles: " + loadPeopleResult.getStatus());
    }
}
```

And the permissions into AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Please help me, what I need to do?

Comment: Just to check, did the sign in process succeed - did you get the consent screen and successfully get the onConnected callback?

Comment: @IanBarber Sign in is succeed, but not able to fetch the people - this is the problem.

Comment: Some things to check: is the app really connected (does it turn up on plus.google.com/apps for the user after they have signed in) - if not could be a problem with the client ID in the developer console not matching the project signing key. Second: is the user a google apps user with G+ disabled. Third: can you make other API calls (e.g. retrieve the profile for the current user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it! My problem was: I do not have specify package correctly:
like this `com.example` but correct way is `com.example.moduledir`

Comment: @stefple in Google Developers Console.